# sum values between start and end dates, for categories, for every day in a period of time in R

Tags: r

I have a set of tasks that have start and end dates. Each task has a category, too. I'd like to specify a particular date range, and sum all of the values within that date range, for each category.  I'd be ok with the results ending up in a wide format (results1) or in a long format (results2).  If either of those makes this easier, that's fine with me.

I tried to make my example below reproducible.

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

dates <- seq(from = ymd("2018-01-01"), to = ymd("2018-01-31"), by = "day") %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  rename(Date = value) %>%
  arrange(Date)


tasks <- data.frame(
  task = c("task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"),
  category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2"),
  start.date = c(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-01-15"), ymd("2018-01-18"), ymd("2018-01-25")),
  end.date = c(ymd("2018-01-07"), ymd("2018-01-27"), ymd("2018-02-15"), ymd("2018-01-31")),
  value = c(1,3,5,7)
)

# desired results example 1: sums in wide format
results1 <- bind_cols(
  dates,
  cat1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  cat2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)
)


# desired results example 2: sums in long format
results2 <- bind_cols(
  bind_rows(dates, dates),
  category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"),
  value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)
)

#graph the results
ggplot(results2, aes(Date, value, color = category)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DF1 = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(tasks, tasks$category), function(df1){
    do.call(rbind, lapply(dates$Date, function(d){
        data.frame(Date = d,
                   category = df1$category[1],
                   value = sum(df1$value[d >= df1$start.date & d <= df1$end.date]),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }))
}))
head(DF1)
#             Date category value
#cat1.1 2018-01-01     cat1     1
#cat1.2 2018-01-02     cat1     1
#cat1.3 2018-01-03     cat1     1
#cat1.4 2018-01-04     cat1     1
#cat1.5 2018-01-05     cat1     1
#cat1.6 2018-01-06     cat1     1

graphics.off()
ggplot(DF1, aes(Date, value, color = category)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `sqldf` could be:

```
 # Data
 require(lubridate)
 require(dplyr)
 require(ggplot2)

 dates <- seq(from = ymd("2018-01-01"), to = ymd("2018-01-31"), by = "day") %>% 
   as_data_frame() %>% 
   rename(Date = value) %>%
   arrange(Date)


 tasks <- data.frame(
   task = c("task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"),
   category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2"),
   start_date = c(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-01-15"), ymd("2018-01-18"), ymd("2018-01-25")),
   end_date = c(ymd("2018-01-07"), ymd("2018-01-27"), ymd("2018-02-15"), ymd("2018-01-31")),
   value = c(1,3,5,7)
 )


 library(sqldf)
 # Dates with valid values 
 result <- sqldf("SELECT dates.Date, tasks.category,  sum(tasks.value) as value
                  FROM dates, tasks 
                  WHERE dates.Date <= tasks.end_date AND
                  dates.Date >= tasks.start_date 
                  GROUP BY dates.Date, tasks.category")

  #Dates with no values for each category is found and joined with result
  final_result <- dates %>% merge(unique(result$category)) %>%
                           mutate(category = y) %>%
                           anti_join(result, by = c("Date","category")) %>% 
                           mutate(value = 0) %>%
                           select(-y) %>%
                           union_all(result) %>% 
                            arrange(category, Date)

final_result
#         Date category value
#1  2018-01-01     cat1     1
#2  2018-01-02     cat1     1
#3  2018-01-03     cat1     1
#4  2018-01-04     cat1     1
#5  2018-01-05     cat1     1
#6  2018-01-06     cat1     1
#7  2018-01-07     cat1     1
#8  2018-01-08     cat1     0
#......so on 
#57 2018-01-26     cat2    12
#58 2018-01-27     cat2    12
#59 2018-01-28     cat2    12
#60 2018-01-29     cat2    12
#61 2018-01-30     cat2    12
#62 2018-01-31     cat2    12
#plot
ggplot(final_result, aes(Date, value, color = category)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear form your results sets what is the goal you're after... but from your description:

> I'd like to specify a particular date range, and sum all of the values within that date range, for each category

Then you'd simply group by date range (i.e. by start and end date) and category and summarise the values:

```
tasks %>% 
group_by(category, start.date, end.date) %>% 
summarise(value = sum(value))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups: category, start.date [?]
category start.date end.date   value
<fct>    <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 cat1     2018-01-01 2018-01-07  1.00
2 cat1     2018-01-15 2018-01-27  3.00
3 cat2     2018-01-18 2018-02-15  5.00
4 cat2     2018-01-25 2018-01-31  7.00
```